# Adding InlineKeyboardButton dynamically

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram quiz bot. I have a list of questions from a certain exam.

The main problem is that questions have different numbers of choices. So I need to create InlineKeyboardButtons dynamically in the loop of questions.

Is it possible to implement?

I'm using a **telebot** library (pyTelegramBotAPI).

Comment: create buttons array in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You gave too little information. I will try to guess.

```
from telebot import types
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
markup.row('a', 'v')
```

Your problem is that you do not know how to pass a variable number of arguments to `row()`? If I right, you can do it this way:

```
from telebot import types
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['a', 'v']])
```

So, I think the problems with the creation of the list should not arise.

> [Documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.replykeyboardmarkup.html)